# Proof of Galois criterion

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

I'm trying to find a proof for the if-direction of the following theorem:

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero and  $f(x)\in F[x]$.  The Galois group of  $f(x)$ is solvable if and only if  $f(x)$ is a solvable polynomial (i.e. Its splitting field is contained in a radical extension of $F$).

Could you give me the main steps I need for a proof? I think I can figure out the details on my own then. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to have a look to the dozens of algebra books which treat this question?

Comment: I only found texts that say basically "this follows from several results we have seen before." I don't manage to see which results we actually need. If you can give me a reference for a good proof I'd be very happy with that as well.

Comment: Do you know the Galois connection between subgroups of field automorphisms and subfields? It's induced by the relation $\varphi \sim a$ iff $\varphi(a)=a$.

Comment: @Berci yes, we didn't use this relation though.